# Unable to add credit card to a managed account on Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, credit-card

I'm working with [Stripe managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts), I can create and retrieve Accounts without problem, but I can not add credit cards to any Stripe Account. I'm using [`Stripe.js`](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js?) to deal with the card creation process, so in the views I collect the card fields and let Stripe.js do the dirty job of validation and processing. If everything is ok, I receive a `stripeToken` from Stripe which is used in my controller to finally associate the managed account and the credit card.

However I receive this error:

`Error creating card: (Status 400) You must provide a card that has the 'currency' field set when adding a card to a Stripe account.`

Therefore I assumed I needed to add the `currency` field in the Card form, so I tried again and then I had this error:

`This card doesn't appear to be a debit card. (when submitting currency from views)`

I already tried to search the error, but somehow there are no real references or previous answers.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Details**

Since I'm testing on my local machine, I'm using Stripe's test Card number:
`4242424242424242` which accepts any `expiration date` and `CVC`

*Here is some code:*

This is how I create my managed account:

```
def create_account(email)
  Stripe::Account.create(
    {
      :country => "US",
      :managed => true,
      :email => email,
      :default_currency => "USD"
    }
  )
end
```

This is how I add the card token to the accounts (based on the [API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card)):

```
def add_card_to_account(account_id, card_token)
  account = get_account(account_id)
  account.external_accounts.create(:external_account => card_token)
end
```

Comment: Hi i'm having the same problem. Did you found a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Stripe [accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object) are payment *destinations* -- they can receive funds, but not provide them.

([Customers](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) are payments *sources*, i.e. they provide funds.)

Currently, Stripe accounts can use two different sorts of external accounts as payout methods (i.e. to retrieve their funds):

- bank accounts
- debit cards (only in the US)

So you can add a debit card as an external account to a US custom account, but not a credit card as those cannot be used to receive funds.

In order to use a debit card as a payout method, the card [token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) must have been created with [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js), using the `currency` parameter. Since this is only possible for US accounts at the moment, the value for the `currency` parameter must be `"usd"`. Here's a simple example of a Stripe.js form that uses the `currency` parameter: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/rprufyg5/

In test mode, you would need to use one of the debit [testing card numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards), e.g. `4000 0566 5566 5556` or `5200 8282 8282 8210`.

Comment: Thank you for that, you probably saved me a lot of time.

Comment: When using Stripe Elements, add the currency parameter to the create token call. `stripe.createToken(card, { currency: 'usd' });`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I have contacted them i found some solution for me.
I am generating token using iOS Stripe SDK.
Its worked for me.

At this time Stripe only supports US-based USD debit cards for card external_accounts. The way you can add the currency parameter to your token is by adding a direct call to

```
self.paymentTextField.cardParams.currency = @"usd";
```

after initializing the STPPaymentCardTextField in your PaymentViewController, like such:

```
// Setup payment view
STPPaymentCardTextField *paymentTextField = [[STPPaymentCardTextField alloc] init];
paymentTextField.delegate = self;
paymentTextField.cursorColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
self.paymentTextField = paymentTextField;
self.paymentTextField.cardParams.currency = @"usd";
[self.view addSubview:paymentTextField];
```